# Refreshing UITableview Section to One With Different Number of Rows

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uitableview

I've recently been working with a UITableView. It is dynamically populated once, then when a user selects an option, I want the list to change to a new one. I'm working with a grouped table with 3 sections and as you click on the rows the three groups need to be repopulated with a varying number of new rows. **While my code works fine when there is the same number of rows in the new section as old, it crashes when that number changes.** Interestingly though, it will wait to crash until it attempts to draw one of the cells that was there previously (the tableView still thinks the section has the old number of rows, tries to draw the cell that is no longer in my model object, and so I think it crashes because it's referencing a value in the new array that doesn't exist.

It crashes here:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath     *)indexPath{

UITableViewCell *cell = nil;

cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MyCell"];

if (cell == nil){

    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                  reuseIdentifier:@"MyCell"];
}

if (indexPath.section==2){
//CRASH BELOW
    cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", (NSString *)[[[[storyArray objectAtIndex:pageNumber]getChoices] objectAtIndex:(unsigned long)indexPath.row]objectAtIndex:0]] ;
}
return cell;
}
```

The function I use to reload the table is here:

```
-(void)changePage:(int)pageChangeNumber{

NSLog(@"The page change! Changing to: %@",[[storyArray objectAtIndex:pageChangeNumber]getTitle]);
pageHeader.text=[[storyArray objectAtIndex:pageChangeNumber] getTitle];
pageBody.text=[[storyArray objectAtIndex:pageChangeNumber] getBody];

[myTableView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:0] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];

[myTableView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:1] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];

 [myTableView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:2] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];

   [myTableView reloadData];    
pageNumber=pageChangeNumber;
NSLog(@"Page Change Done");
}
```

I've also changed the numberofRowsInSection to be dynamic...

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    NSLog(@"Recounting Rows");
if (section==2){
    return [[[storyArray objectAtIndex:pageNumber]getChoices] count];
} else {
    return 0;
}

}
```

Any ideas on how I can get this working when the number of rows per section changes?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what crash you're getting, but I ran into crashes if the `numberOfSectionsInTableView:` or `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` methods returned different numbers of rows while the table was restructuring itself.

For example, UITableView calls those methods many times while it is redrawing (including during animations). In my backend, some of the values were changing during animation.

I had to take special care to synchronize those values before changing the UITableView

Answer (score 1):

Before you update your table view's data and call reloadSections you need to first call `[myTableView beginUpdates]` and once you're done `[myTableView endUpdates]`